# How do I perform a "get" call to an external API, and then display the JSON results on a page in my WordPress site?

Tags: customization, api, json, membership, plugin-json-api

A client has an external API that is storing all member info.

My tasks are:

a.) Create a 'Member Profile Search' page on his site, where users can search for members using certain keywords.

b.) When the submit button on the search page is clicked, perform a "get" call to the external API, that will return JSON objects, and then display the results in a page on the site - possibly, the same page as the search page

My questions:

1.) Is there a plugin that I can use to achieve this?

2.) If there's no solution using an available plugin, how can I accomplish this?

I'm a web developer and have customized a few WP sites, but nothing requiring this level of expertise, so your help would be **greatly** appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: A couple resources that might help: [`wp_safe_remote_get()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_remote_get/) to get the API data, and [`json_decode()`](https://php.net/json_decode) to decode the JSON data once you've got it.

Comment: @PatJ Thanks for your prompt response. How can I use these resources to accomplish my goals?

Comment: Do you need to authenticate against this API as well? I find it strange you can blindly search member data...There are numerous ways to achieve this (including what's posted above), what have you tried?... for starters look at jQuery' s `$.get` method to obtain the data

Comment: @Ray Yes! You would need to authenticate against this API. So far, I have been searching for plugins that can help me achieve this. Being that I haven't done anything like this, I'm clueless as to where to begin. Can you expatiate on the numerous ways to accomplish these tasks?

Comment: So, I've come to the conclusion that I'll have to create a plugin, and possibly a new page template. Can I use one plugin for the search, the "get" call, and also display the results on a page? I apologize if my questions are annoying, I'm in uncharted waters. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Creating your own plugin is a good solution. You can have 1-3 functions for the API calls and attach them to filters then 1-2 functions and filters for displaying the form and search results from the API. If you would attempt and give us some code samples, we'll be happy to help. Divide and conquer each task and combine them after each piece is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up developing a plugin using AJAX to make the calls to the API